# nodejs - unable to write files in linux server

Tags: node.js, linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I have hosted a node server in AWS. Server runs fine. In server, a file (for eg, abc.pdf) is generated programmatically. The file gets saved in `/tmp` location.

I wanted this file in another location `/home/ubuntu/nodeserver/file/` But to this location, file is not getting saved. It only works in `tmp` folder.

I gave full permission to the folder but still, it's not working.

This is how I specified path for `tmp` folder

```
file:///tmp/
```

But the path I gave for the other folder is not working

```
file:///home/ubuntu/nodeserver/file
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue

The path should have been like this

```
file://home/ubuntu/nodeserver/file
```